# How can I install Auto-PyTorch on Windows 10 from requirements.txt?

Tags: python, powershell, neural-network, pytorch

I have been trying to install Auto-PyTorch, an automatic Neural Network tuning system (more info about installation here: https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch), in a Windows 10 system. The installation steps are as follow:

```
$ cd install/path
$ git clone https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch.git
$ cd Auto-PyTorch
$ cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
$ python setup.py install
```

However, I can't get around the following line of code:

```
cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
```

Once I get there, the following Windows PowerShell error is raised:

```
xargs : The term 'xargs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 

operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:86
+ ... read.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'; cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xargs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Note that I passed the following line of code so that the error is thrown in English (I am Spanish):

```
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'; cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
```

I'm not an expert on PowerShell, so I would greatly appreciate your help.

Best regards!

Comment: What is `xargs`?

Comment: Hi! Check @mklement0 's answer to my question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804977/13894541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running on *Windows PowerShell*, only command-line utilities natively available *on Windows* can be assumed to be available - and [`xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html), a *Unix* utility, is *not* among them.
(While `git` also isn't natively available, it looks like you've already installed it).

Here's a translation of your code into native PowerShell code (note that `cd` is a built-in alias for [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Location), and, on Windows only, `cat` is a built-in alias for [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content); `%` is a built-in alias for the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) cmdlet):

```
Set-Location install/path
git clone https://github.com/automl/Auto-PyTorch.git
Set-Location Auto-PyTorch
Get-Content requirements.txt | % { pip install $_ }
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @BorjaGarcia; my pleasure.